# Get workers against legal entity in Dynamics AX 2012

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

I need to retrieve list of all workers against the current legal entity.

I want to show the retrieved list in a drop down, but the first part is how to get it?

Comment: This feature is standard in the HCMWorkerLookup form. This lookup is used when you use the EDT HcmWorkerRecId for you field. On that lookup there is an option to show only the workers from the current legal entity. Is there a reason why you are not using the default lookup? Do you have other requirements that don't allow you to use it?

Answer (score 0):

Particularly for Lookup, You can use EDT named 'SmmActivityWorker' for your table/Form control.
A reference group will be created if used from table and please create Reference group manually if using directly as a control on forms.
You can refer Responsible field under 'Custtable' form.